# Using Append tool to append address number values from one point feature class to another gives ERROR 001156

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, append, error-001156

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

I am having a problem with the append tool, specifically when appending one field in my attribute table.  I am trying to append the address number field which is a text field with a field length of 6 using the address field from the input attribute table which is text field with a length of 5.  It keep getting this error message.

Does anyone have suggestion or workaround for this?

[image: Error Message]

[image: Append Tool Settings in ModelBuilder]

[image: Input Field Attributes]

[image: OutputFieldAttributes]

Comment: The field mapping is having an issue. Look at the input record before and the actual problem record; perhaps there is blank padding at front and end that is making it too long.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text instead of, or as well as, a picture.